# Problems opening heapsnapshot files

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools

The Snapshot was taken through a forwarded port, from a pod in k8s.

The error is:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '12483')

[image: Error Screenshot]

[See heapsnapshot file](https://ufile.io/sy8lm09s)

1. Is there anyway to repair the file?
2. Is the an alternative viewer that might work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a file corruption error, i exported a new heapsnapshot and it worked fine